# How the IBM MobileFirst application is protected from phishing?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

What are the attributes in the code that are actually protecting the IBM MobileFirst hybrid application from phishing. If possible please explain with an example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please elaborate what do you mean specifically by "phishing" when it comes to mobile applications. Which threats are you looking to stop?

Answer (score 1):

Definition of "phishing":

> Phishing is the attempt to acquire sensitive information such as
>   usernames, passwords, and credit card details (and sometimes,
>   indirectly, money), often for malicious reasons, by masquerading as a
>   trustworthy entity in an electronic communication.

Trying to think about that in mobile apps terms, I would say that the closest is "Man in the middle" attack, where an attacker is in between the server and the client, attempting to mask as the intended destination of the requests originating from the client application.

In MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1 there is Certificate Pinning support which enables thwarting such attempts. You can read more about it here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/c_cert_pinning_intro.html?lang=en

Please, when asking a question and if seeking a serious answer, take a moment to compose a question that is fully understandable.

Comment: Thank you very much and next time I will make my question in detail.